# D3js WebWorker for crawling Data

Tags: javascript, rest, d3.js, web-worker

I have different entities that share a bidirectional connection. So entity1 has a connection with entity2 with two roles holding the id of entity1 and entity2. those roles are accessible through a REST API.
Now I want to let a web worker crawl through the connections and all subsequent connections and update a force directed graph or network graph with all those connections.
How can I update a force graph with async data? And how can I keep track of all visited nodes so I don't get circular references?
It would be nice if someone could give me a general example on how to request data from a remote api, inlcuding possible paging, and updating a d3js chart with the data. All examples I found always have a static json file that is read for data.

Comment: Your question is way too broad for StackOverflow and will probably be closed.  But [here's one example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/01ab2e85e8727d6529d20391c0fd9a16) I worked off of combining a web worker and d3 force.

Comment: The main problem I have is to gather remote data so that I can display the forceSimulation, or to update it while requesting data.